# How to compare elementwise two columns in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

This should be very simple, but for some reason I can't figure out how to do that. I have dataframe with many columns, and variables with names of two columns. I want to calculate number of rows where `x_col < y_col` . I wanted to use `df.filter().count()` approach since it worked fine in pandas, but for some reason it refuses to work properly with my implementation:

```
x_col = col(self.column_x)  # self.column_x is a string
y_col = col(self.column_y)  # same here

tmp_df = df.filter(x_col < y_col)
cnt = tmp_df.count()
```

It worked just fine previously when instead of one of the columns was just a number, so I suspect that I'm missing some conversion to make it evaluate this as data instead of comparing columns objects?

P.S. Ideally it should work with that `relation` function as well

```
if self.strict:
    relation = lambda x, y: x < y
else:
    relation = lambda x, y: x <= y
tmp_df = df.filter(relation(x_col, y_col))
```

but at this point it doesn't matter to me and I'm down to make `if` with `<=` and `<` if that would work

Comment: "one of the columns was just a number" - so now it compares like `x_col < 10` ? " it refuses to work" - how it appears, error, no results?

Comment: Worked just fine. I had `df.filter(relation(col(self.column)))` where relation was `relation = lambda x: x < some_value` in prev function and it worked correctly  - I'm comparing with pandas. But when I changed it to comparing two columns like in question PS part it started to work weird. Firstly I thought that it was because of missing values, but it works wrong on just one row table, so that's not the case.